# CREATE DATABASE using file in default path

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to create an SQL script that creates a database.  Right now, I have this:

```
CREATE DATABASE [Documents] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'Documents', FILENAME = N'Documents.mdf')
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'Documents_log', FILENAME = N'Documents_log.ldf')
 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

However, this generates the following error:

```
Msg 5105, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
A file activation error occurred. The physical file name 'Documents.mdf' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.
Msg 1802, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
```

I know the problem is that I did not specify fully qualified path for the filenames.  But I want to be able to run this script regardless of the directory structure of the database server.  Is there some way to use a default path?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can create a database without specifying file details, like:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE Documents;
```

Comment: True, but what if I need to specify additional attributes like SIZE and FILEGROWTH? 

I've seen the solutions using XP's to read the registry but what if you aren't running on the default instance?   That registry key/value wouldn't give the right answer.

Still searching so I don't really consider this answered myself.

Comment: after create database add alter database script for specify additional attributes like SIZE and FILEGROWTH.

Answer (score 79):

Create the database 'Documents' and give file properties through an alter.

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE DATABASE [Documents]
GO

ALTER DATABASE [Documents] MODIFY FILE
( NAME = N'Documents', SIZE = 512MB, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
GO

ALTER DATABASE [Documents] MODIFY FILE
( NAME = N'Documents_log', SIZE = 256MB, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10% )
GO
```

This script is more portable and can be deployed in multiple servers without any modifications.

Comment: Also you can use `NEWNAME` if you want to amend the logical name; i.e. `NAME` references the original name, `NEWNAME` says what to change it to.  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4407/rename-logical-database-file-name-for-a-sql-server-database/

Answer (score 5):

See [How do I find the data directory for a SQL Server instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883071/how-do-i-find-the-data-directory-for-a-sql-server-instance)

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or higher, you can find the default path using

```
select 
  InstanceDefaultDataPath = serverproperty('InstanceDefaultDataPath'),
  InstanceDefaultLogPath = serverproperty('InstanceDefaultLogPath')
```

You can then use exec() to construct your CREATE DATABASE statement.

This is useful if you want the physical file names of your database to be different from the default name.

Comment: Thanks. However how do I use this in the CREATE DATABASE script? Executing CREATE DATABASE [Documents] 
( NAME = N'Documents', FILENAME = @InstanceDefaultDataPath + N'Documents.mdf' ...   gives an error  - you can't concatenate the result of your query with the DB dame inside a CREATE DATABASE script

Comment: @ReversedEngineer I think you would need to build the CREATE DATABASE statement and execute it dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Adding onto @Blade's answer. Here's an example of getting the default path server properties and using the EXECUTE method:

```
DECLARE @DefaultDataPath varchar(max)
SET @DefaultDataPath = (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max), SERVERPROPERTY('INSTANCEDEFAULTDATAPATH')))
DECLARE @DefaultLogPath varchar(max)
SET @DefaultLogPath = (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max), SERVERPROPERTY('INSTANCEDEFAULTLOGPATH')))

EXECUTE('
CREATE DATABASE [blah] ON PRIMARY
( NAME = N''blah'', FILENAME = ''' + @DefaultDataPath + 'blah.mdf'', SIZE = 167872KB, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 16384KB )
 LOG ON
( NAME = N''blah_Log'', FILENAME = ''' + @DefaultDataPath + 'blah_Log.mdf'', SIZE = 2048KB, MAXSIZE = 2048GB, FILEGROWTH = 16384KB );
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
');
GO
```

Note that if you do a `USE` to switch dbs, the local variable scope is lost. So if you're creating multiple dbs in a script, either create them all at the beginning or copy the variables' declare/set to each create.

Answer (score 1):

Take a Look on how to create a [Default Path](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/4297b9b0-84a2-4198-9599-c156847bed2f). See if it helps on what you are looking for.

Cheers,

Comment: proost!, prost!, santé, salute, salud!, živjeli!, kippis!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can do

```
CREATE DATABASE [Documents]
```

without the ON .... and it will get created with defaults for path and the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Taking in account all the answers and some information from the Internet I played with the next code:

```
USE [master];
DECLARE @DataBaseName varchar(max) = 'TEST1';
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = @DataBaseName)
BEGIN
PRINT(@DataBaseName + ' database already exists, dropping...');
EXEC('ALTER DATABASE ' + @DataBaseName + ' SET OFFLINE ' + ' WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE');
EXEC('ALTER DATABASE ' + @DataBaseName + ' SET ONLINE');
EXEC('DROP DATABASE '  + @DataBaseName);
END;

PRINT(@DataBaseName + ' is being created...');
EXEC('CREATE DATABASE [' + @DataBaseName +']; ALTER DATABASE [' + @DataBaseName + '] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE; ALTER DATABASE [' + @DataBaseName + '] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = ' + @DataBaseName + ', SIZE = 512MB, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ); ALTER DATABASE [' + @DataBaseName + '] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = ' + @DataBaseName + '_log' + ', SIZE = 256MB, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10% )');
```

I use it as the 'tool' for some testing needs.
I left 2 different approaches to use EXEC per command (after IF operator) and to execute several commands at once.
Hope it will help somebody.