# query path tp mssql server table with delphi

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado

under [MSSQL ATTACH DATABASE SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829271/how-can-i-clone-an-sql-server-database-on-the-same-server-in-sql-server-2008-exp/3830948#3830948) there is a nice script to attach / detach a database on a MSSQL server.  Is there any system variable in Delphi I can use to detect the path the the database files by source code ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get path of a data file of a certain database, you'll need to query the [`sys.master_files`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186782.aspx) table. In its `physical_name` column is stored the file name of a database data file, so running a query like this should give you what you need:

```sql
SELECT
  physical_name
FROM
  sys.master_files
WHERE
  database_id = DB_ID(N'your_database_name')
```

Comment: I doubt that there is an entry for a file he wants to **attach** ;-).

Comment: +1. I think it's obvious OP is looking for the `OriginalDB` path (the one that needs to be detach).

Answer (score 0):

You can put your database file wherever you want (except network drives, of course), as long as the SQL-Server account has appropriate rights to the file.

In case you want to stick with the default settings, i.e. the default database location/path, see this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883071/how-do-i-find-the-data-directory-for-a-sql-server-instance) for details.