# SQL Server find storing location issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know if there is any query that can be used to determine which drive, i.e. `C:\` drive, SQL Server is located on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean where the server files are installed, or where files for a particular database are? Or the default data directory? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, physical_name AS current_file_location FROM sys.master_files;
```

You can also use an undocumented system stored procedure to get the installation folder, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @Path VARCHAR(100);
SELECT @Path = NULL;
EXEC MASTER..xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\ClientSetup', 'SQLPath', @Path OUTPUT;
SELECT @Path;
```

Comment: To add to the completeness of your answer, if after the data directory, and OP is on SQL Server 2012 or newer, there's a cleaner way than using the registry: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16681314